# google index an Post type page I do not want

Tags: archives, post-type

I created a Custom Post type for my client's site, and everything works fine.
but, I found that google index an archive page that I do not want.
here is the code of my Post Type:

```
    $apres_repas_options = array(
    'labels' => $apres_repas_labels, // array of : name , singular_name ......
    'description' => 'Holds our Après repas and pizza specific data',
    'public' => true,
    'menu_icon' => dirname(plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)).'/assets/images/after-meal.png',
    'supports' => array('title', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail'),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'apres-repas'
    )
);
```

and this the URL that google index and i don't want :[Pizza Halal à Vauréal](https://alan-pizza.fr/apres-repas/)

thank your for your helps

Comment: So set `'has_archive'` to `false`...

Comment: you may want to go into googles webmaster too and tell it not to index that page as well if it's already been indexed.

Comment: i have change the has_archive to false , but wordpress display now a page with body class <body class="blog ....">

Comment: rudtek , hi , i try to add tag noindex , nofolow but stil google explore this page